# How many times a function such as NOW() is called in mysql query

Tags: mysql

Please consider following sample query

```
SELECT * FROM subscriber WHERE subscription_date>DATE(NOW()-INTERVAL 10 DAY)
```

My question is, if there are 100 records in subscriber table, then how many times the functions `NOW()` and `DATE()` will be called? Will these functions be evaluated for comparing with every row, or will they be evaluated just once in the start of the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be called once. MySQL tries to evaluate the `WHERE` clause first, so internally it converts it into a static value.

BTW: by using `NOW()` your query won't be cached in MySQL, so when this query is called again some seconds later it has to executed again instead. So better use `DATE('2012-01-05 04:00:00'-INTERVAL 10 DAY)`